# Google Map embed in IE Only Shows #

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps

I have embedded the code below and work in all browsers except IE.  I thought this was due to the new XSS filter from IE but I am not sure.  It is only showing a hash tag (#), that is it.  I don't want the user to have to modify their IE setting or download a new browser.  I would rather find a hack that will make this work in IE.

I have searched all the other questions pertaining to this and none have a solution that fits this exact problem.  You can view the code below:

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=%2B14%C2%B0+21'+18.93%22,+-90%C2%B0+34'+19.52%22&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=53.212719,100.810547&amp;t=h&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=14.355258,-90.572089&amp;spn=0.035796,0.055747&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="890" height="300"></iframe>
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove the single quote(') of the URL

[http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=%2B14%C2%B0+21'+18.93%22,+-90%C2%B0+34'+19.52%22&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=53.212719,100.810547&t=h&ie=UTF8&ll=14.355258,-90.572089&spn=0.035796,0.055747&z=14&output=embed](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=%2b14%C2%B0%2021%27%2018.93%22,%20-90%C2%B0%2034%27%2019.52%22&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=53.212719,100.810547&t=h&ie=UTF8&ll=14.355258,-90.572089&spn=0.035796,0.055747&z=14&output=embed)

becomes

[http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=%2B14%C2%B0+21+18.93%22,+-90%C2%B0+34+19.52%22&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=53.212719,100.810547&t=h&ie=UTF8&ll=14.355258,-90.572089&spn=0.035796,0.055747&z=14&output=embed](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=%2b14%C2%B0%2021%2018.93%22,%20-90%C2%B0%2034%2019.52%22&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=53.212719,100.810547&t=h&ie=UTF8&ll=14.355258,-90.572089&spn=0.035796,0.055747&z=14&output=embed)

For an unknown reason, IE doesn't like it...

[EDIT]

It the problem persists, it seems that the only solution is to use Gmaps API [Here is an simple example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple)

Comment: Hi Philippe, it worked for a few minutes and then rendered # again.  Do you think this is an IE filter issue?

Comment: I Think the only solution would be to use Gmaps API Here is an simple example : https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Comment: @Matt: after doing what Philippe suggested make sure to clear your cache. (or reload using Ctrl+F5).

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I just spoke to someone and they said the same so I will do that.  Thank you!

Comment: Marcelo, thank you for reminding me:)  I did that already but no luck.

Comment: Philippe, update your answer and I will accept, thanks again.